# Please help me with SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, select

Depreciation table

[image]

Attached image is my depreciation table. From this ,I want an SQL Query which returns all asset tags with maximum `depr_date`. that means asset tag with last depreciation date.

I want something like this

```
asset_tag    depr_date
----------------------
TB29         2015-04-11
TB30         2015-03-11
PC626        2015-04-10
```

Comment: you are asking last depreciation but at the same time your output seems to have range of last depreciation rates... I think you need to make it much more clear

Comment: i want asset_tag with last depreciation date

Comment: I want something like this
is diffrent then your qustion are you clear about what you want to get ?

Comment: i got the answer frm #Kapil Jain (below).  that is what i want. im sry for u not asking the question clearly..thnx for the rplys

Answer (score 2):

Try below one.

```
SELECT asset_tag, max(depr_date) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY asset_tag
```

Comment: Be sure u did checked it as ANSWERED